# Most efficient way to get a column range into a 1D array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google form that collects responses in a linked spreadsheet. One of the fields in the form is `Username` (column B in the sheet). I'm writing a script to notify me when a new user (unique username) makes a submission. To do this, I:

1. Get all the values in column B except the latest one
2. Get the latest username
3. Check if the latest username is in the list of values (do something if not).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
function isUserNew() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("INSERT ID HERE");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  var last_row_number = sheet.getLastRow()
  var penultimate_row_number = (last_row_number-1)
  var latest_username = sheet.getRange(last_row_number, 2).getValue()
  var usernames = sheet.getRange("B2:B" + penultimate_row_number).getValues();
}
```

This gives me a 2D array `usernames` that looks like `[[UserA],[UserB],[UserC],[UserC],[UserA],[UserX]].` Then I tried `if (usernames.indexOf(latest_username) == -1` but this doesn't work - it only works for a 1D array. I thought of converting the array to 1D using a loop:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(usernames[i][0]);
  }
```

This makes the logger correctly log all the usernames I want, but I don't know how to put them into an array.

2 main questions:

1. **How do I get the values into an array** instead of the Logger?
2. **Is this the best way to do what I'm trying to do?** It seems unnecessary that every time there's a submission, I grab a 2D array, convert to 1D, and compare. The column data is not going to change, it only grows by 1 every time. How will this impact run time as the data grows into the 1000s?

Comment: Use `Array#map`: `var users1d = usernames.map(function (row) { return row[0]; });` Apps Script has a few of the more recent `Array` methods available - they'll show up in autocomplete. You can review how they work on your JavaScript language reference of choice, like MDN.

Comment: @tehhowch sorry for the delayed response and thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you could flatten the array and compare with `indexOf` as you're doing:

```
var flattened_usernames = [] ;
for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
    flattened_usernames.push(usernames[i][0]);
}
```

But you're better off just doing the check inside the loop:

```
if (usernames[i][0] === latest_username)
```

By the way, I assume you know how to grab the username directly from the `onFormSubmit` event rather than grabbing it from the last row of the sheet. But if not you should learn how to do that!

Comment: That makes sense, I'll try putting it inside the loop, thanks! Could you elaborate on the `onFormSubmit` part? My plan was to create a form submit trigger (`Edit > Current project's triggers`) to run the function, is there a different way?

Comment: If you add an argument to the function, isUserNew(e), then the onFormSubmit trigger will pass the form submission data to your function. Then you could just get the latest username like this: `var username = e.namedValues["User name"][0]`. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Answer (score 2):

The `getValues()` returned from a column is consistently structured, so I have used `range.getValues().flat()` for this.

Comment: if you are passing a 2D range as input in a custom function/formula, you can just use the input.flat() to get a 1D array from the range passed to the function

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var usernames = sheet.getRange("B2:B" + penultimate_row_number).getValues();
```

Do:

```
var usernames = [].concat(...sheet.getRange("B2:B" + penultimate_row_number).getValues());
```

This flattens the 2d result of a column into a 1d array. If it's not the shortest way it should be close. I don't know about the efficiency.